# wxButton still looking selected after next button gets selected

Tags: c++, user-interface, windows-7, focus, wxwidgets

There are several wxButton on the panel. wxButton blinks when it is focused, but after a new button gets selected, previous does not stop to blink. Only two of them are looking selected, e.g. if third gets selected the first one looks fine etc.

I tried stopping propagation of SetFocus events, subclassing wxButton and overriding methods

```
bool AcceptsFocusFromKeyboard() const { 
    return false;
}


virtual bool AcceptsFocus() const {
    return false;
}
```

but without results.

This happens only on Windows 7, Win 8.1 and Mac looks as expected.

Anyone had the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to do anything special for the focus to work correctly, just make sure you do *not* intercept, without skipping, any focus events as doing this can indeed break things as [mentioned in the documentation](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_focus_event.html).

If you can reproduce the problem with simple changes in one of wxWidgets samples with wxWidgets 3, please [open a ticket](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/newticket) explaining how to do it.

Comment: The two things I forgot to mention: 1) wxWidgets version is not the latest, it is 2.8 (can't upgrade this branch, update is getting done on other) 2) this can be reproduced even with simple dialog with only two buttons (even with Dialog Blocks test option - no event skipping etc)

Comment: You might be right about the focus, but focus is my prime suspect for now.

Comment: I seem to remember there was a bug in the default button management code a long, long time ago, if you're using 2.8 you could be affected by it. Unfortunately I don't have enough time to point you to the exact commit that fixed this, all I can say is that it was quite some time ago and must have affected one of `src/msw/{button,toplevel}.cpp`.